# The required Active Directory Rights Management Service Client (MSPIC.DLL) is presenet but could not be configured properly

Tags: sharepoint-server, irm

I have a SharePoint Farm that consists of five servers:

1-DB
2-Web FrontEnd & Distributed Cache servers
2-Application & Search Servers

I have configured one of our domain servers to be an RMS server. After, installing the RMS service on the server, I tried to add it to SharePoint but I got the following error:

```
The required Active Directory Rights Management Service Client (MSPIC.DLL) is presenet but could not be configured properly. IRM will not work until the client is configured properly.
```

I have searched the web for the solution but to no avail.

I have tried to give permissions to the farm and web application account on ServerCertification.asmx
I have also tried importing the certificate for the SharePointAdministration account.

I have checked the event viewer log and I have the following errors:

```
Event ID 8321 A certificate validation took xxxxx milliseconds ...
Event ID 6398 The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob threw an exception ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to giving the Web Application Pool account and the SharePoint Farm account the permission to read and execute *_wmcs\certification\ServerCertification.asmx*, I have done the following:

The name of the certificate must match the new of the RMS server. e,g: if the RMS server is called RMS.abc.local then that should be the name of the certificate as well.

I have added the certificate to the trusted root authority in all of my SharePoint servers.

I have then installed the RMS Analyzer tool which checks your configuration and corrects all the wrong configurations, if any, from [this URL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46437).

Finally, I have reset the MSPIC settings by following the instructions mentioned in [this great article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19251.ad-rms-troubleshooting-reset-the-client-msipc.aspx).

I am not sure if one or all these steps are what fixed my problem. Nonetheless, I hope that they benefit anyone who may face the same problem!